# PHP delete the last word in string by specific word

Tags: php

How can i delete the last word by a specific word in a string?

So example, this is the string

```
$string = 'bla test bla test bla test bla test bla'
```

Now i want to delete `test` but just the last one, not everyone.
Output must be this

```
$string = 'bla test bla test bla test bla bla'
```

i just find str_replace and something, but than i delete every test and not only the last one...
I also searched here but not finding something to delete the specific word that i will delete. Jsut find something with trim last space or something. But AFTER the last word i search for, there can be more words

Comment: @tevved Try this: `echo preg_replace('~test(?!.*test)~', '', $string);`

Comment: What if there is only 1 `test` in the word?

Comment: @nice_dev doesn't matter

Comment: @reformed Ok. I am just waiting for OP to confirm that.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$string = 'bla test bla test bla test bla test bla';

echo preg_replace('~ test(?!.* test)~', '', $string);
```

Comment: than all are deleted :/

Comment: No, the code above outputs: `bla test bla test bla test bla bla`

Comment: @reformed is right, the negative lookahead in the regex will prevent the replace of other `test` than the last one, in particular:

`~` are the delimiter, ` test` is the what the regex must replace and `(?!.* test)` is a negative lookahead that tell not to accept a `test` followed by other everything followed by "test". The only caveat is that regex will "fail" in a case such `bla test bla test bla test bla testing bla` returning `bla test bla test bla test blaing bla`

Answer (score 0):

A manual way of doing it would be to split the string with a separator into an array, detect last subject position (in reverse), then unset and glue it back together.

```
var_dump(remove_last('bla test bla test bla test bla test bla', 'test', ' '));

function remove_last(string $text, string $subject, string $separator): string {
    $parts = explode($separator, $text);
    $pos = count($parts) -1 -array_search($subject, array_reverse($parts));

    if ($parts[$pos] ?? false) {
        unset($parts[$pos]);
    }

    return implode($separator, $parts);
}
```

https://3v4l.org/X0F13

Another way using `substr_replace()`:

```
var_dump(remove_last('bla test bla test bla test bla test bla', 'test', ' '));

function remove_last(string $text, string $subject, string $separator): string {
    if (($offset = strrpos($text, "$separator$subject")) === false) {
        $offset = strrpos($text, "$subject$separate");
    }
    
    if ($offset !== false) {
        return substr_replace($text, '', $offset, strlen("$separator$subject"));
    }
    
    return $text;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/ZUULc

Answer (score 0):

First revert the string:
'bla test bla test bla test bla test bla' becomes 'alb tset alb tset alb tset alb tset alb'.
Then replace in this string the reversed version of the string to be replaced with the reversed version of the string to replace it with.
So: replace ' tset ' with ' ' (add spaces to force that full words are being replaced):
'alb tset alb tset alb tset alb tset alb' becomes 'alb alb tset alb tset alb tset alb'.
Then revert it again:
'alb alb tset alb tset alb tset alb' becomes 'bla test bla test bla test bla bla'.
You can put it in a oneliner:

```html
<?php
$string = 'bla test bla test bla test bla test bla';
$word = 'test';
echo strrev(preg_replace('/'.preg_quote(' '.strrev($word).' ', '/').'/', ' ', strrev($string), 1));
```

Comment: Why should the OP ___try this___? **Good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer. If it is well answered maybe they will UpVote it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the provided String Function [`strrpos()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos) Find needle in string processing from right to left.

and [`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) you can do this quite simply

```
$string = 'bla test bla test bla test bla test bla';
$needle = 'test';
echo $string . PHP_EOL;
$pos = strrpos($string, $needle, 0);
if ( $pos !== FALSE ){
    // it was found in the string
    $new_string = substr_replace($string, '', $pos, strlen('test '));
} else {
    echo "$needle not found in the string";
}
echo $new_string .PHP_EOL;
```

RESULT

```
bla test bla test bla test bla test bla
bla test bla test bla test bla bla
```